# chef/knife environment configuration help

Tags: chef, knife

I have the following as my knife.rb:

```
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                'user'
client_key               '/home/user/.chef/user.pem'
validation_client_name   'chef-validator'
validation_key           '~/.chef/validation.pem'
chef_server_url          'url:4000'
cache_type               'BasicFile'
cache_options( :path => '/home/user/.chef/checksums' )
cookbook_path [ './', './site-cookbooks' ]
```

I can do "knife cookbook list" and all that fun stuff just fine, but when I go to edit I get:

```
# knife node edit test.domain.com -c knife.rb -e vim
ERROR: ArgumentError: Attribute chef_environment is not defined!
```

I have an environment set up:

```
# knife environment list
  _default
  production
```

and the node I'm trying to edit is on that environment. I have tried using the -E param, as well as adding an "environment" and "chef_environment" parameter to my knife.rb (the docs are a bit ambiguous as to which I should use), but to no avail. Anyone have any advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Chef do you have installed on the local system where you're using Knife? What version is running on the Chef Server? (I presume that with a 'url:4000' chef_server_url you're running your own server instead of Opscode's).

You can get additional information out of knife with '-VV'.

```
knife node edit test.example.com -c knife.rb -e vim -VV
```

The setting in the knife.rb for the default environment to use is `environment`. On the node itself, `chef_environment` is a method to the Node object that returns the value of the node's environment and it is not an attribute.

Also, I'd recommend putting knife.rb in the `.chef` directory of your Chef Repository, or in your home directory. Knife will detect the configuration automatically by looking for `.chef/knife.rb`, similar to git.

Knife will also use the editor specified in the shell environment variable, EDITOR, too.

```
export EDITOR=`which vim`
```

Will have it use vim.